# Get RTP stream media capabilities without SDP file (Gstreamer)

Tags: video, streaming, gstreamer, rtp

I'm developing an RTP video player using Gstreamer. What it needs to do is to only render video received from a fixed source (127.0.0.1). 
I also need to support various audio and video encodings.

Gstreamer needs media capabilities (caps) to correctly manage RTP streams, specifying them directly or obtaining them from SDP files.

There is a way to get these informations (caps) automatically from RTP stream (without using SDP file)?

Answer (score 0):

you can use signal handlers to resolve this problem with rtpbin element.
You have to use the signal "pad-added" for linking appropriate element and "request-pt-map" to set the appropriate caps on pad.
you can refer link. : http://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/latest/gst-plugins-good-plugins-0.10/gst-plugins-good-plugins-gstrtpbin.html#GstRtpBin-request-pt-map

Note : set caps "application/x-rtp,..." to udpsrc for catching rtp media dynamically.

Comment: Setting caps="application/x-rtp,..." gives me error.